# str_replace string and similar string

Tags: php, string, replace, strict

I'm trying to use the `str_replace()` function with an array of strings.

My problem is that some strings in my array contains another string.

Here is an example:

I have a category of products such as:

```
$product1 = 'COLLIERPEND';
$product2 = 'COLLIER';
```

And I want to transform all of them into `co`.

```
str_replace(array("COLLIER", "COLLIERPEND"), 'co', $product#);
```

The result is:

```
$product1 = 'coPEND';
$product2 = 'co';
```

I could just change the order in the array, but I have too many categories.

Is there a function that could help me achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [regular expression based replacements](http://php.net/preg_replace), search for `\bCOLLIER\b` to replace with co. That way you're finding word boundaries on each side of the search word, so you shouldn't have sub-word issues.

Alternately (since I don't fully understand your problem) sort your list by length, longest first.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: I was affraid about the length-sorting because of the number of different strings, but it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you should revise it to (list it by longer string first):

```
str_replace(array("COLLIERPEND", "COLLIER"), 'co', $product#);
```